# Docker Not Linking Containers

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04

I'm following [the userguide on dockerlinks](http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/)

I followed these steps as follows :

- `sudo docker run -d --name db training/postgres`
- `sudo docker run -d -P --name web --link db:db training/webapp python app.py`
- `sudo docker inspect -f "{{ .HostConfig.Links }}" web`

In this last step, the guide asserts the return value of `[/db:/web/db]`

What I'm receiving is `<no value>`

**Why are the containers not linking?**

Comment: When you have completed the steps above, what does the `docker ps` command say?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ucIxYW7.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The apt-get repositories include docker version 1.0.1, but `HostConfig.Links` doesn't show up in the documentation until version 1.3 (See the version switcher under the "Search the Docs").

You can verify that this is the problem by running `docker --version`.

If you want the latest version of docker (1.4), you should uninstall docker.io and follow the directions here: http://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#docker-maintained-package-installation . In particular see the note, as you can just run:

```
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ubuntu/ | sudo sh
```

That will also give you some other nice features that are missing from the version in the Ubuntu repository, such as [exec](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#exec).